# Windows Store app: Unable to create x64 app package

Tags: windows-store-apps, package

I receive the following error:

> error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "obj\x64\Release\\project_name.xr.xml" because it was not found.

**NOTE:**
The specified path from the error message is already an invalid path because of the two back-slashes (i.e. "\\") before the actual "xr.xml" file.

In other words, the system is looking for a directory path that is invalid.

Is this a **VS2013** bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by resolving the various warnings that I received from building the solution.
After I resolved several warnings, I attempted to create a package again and was successful.